# Normal distribution with complex mean?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I just calculated the characteristic function of a normally distributed variable. However, what's weird is that I used the assumption that a noormally distributed variable can have a complex mean, even if I'm just integrating over the real line.

Perhaps I only accidentally got the right answer?

I got to this point:

$$f(L) =e^{iL\mu-0.5 L^2\sigma^2} \int \frac {1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-(\mu+iL\sigma^2))^2}{2\sigma^2}} \, dx = e^{iL\mu-0.5 L^2\sigma^2}$$

Does this make sense? if so, why would it, given that we are only integrating over the real line? Yet the answer is correct.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)) says "characteristic functions may generally be complex-valued"  and "real-valued [if] it corresponds to a random variable that is symmetric around the origin".  Your integration is over real $x$ and uses real $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ but the integrand can be complex valued

Comment: I dont have a probl m with the fact that the characteristic function is complex valued. i have a problem with the fact that im integrating over a normal distribution with mean $/mu +iL\sigma^2$, which is complex. How can the mean be complex if the values im integrating over are all real?

Comment: The mean $\mu$ is not complex in that expression.  What may be complex is $e^{iLx}$ in your calculation of the characteristic function  $f(L)=\mathbb{E}[e^{iLx}]$ which involves the integration of a complex valued function along the real line

Comment: Using $\int e^{-\frac{(x-(\mu+iL\sigma^2))^2}{2\sigma^2}}= {\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}$ is as true for complex valued $\mu+iL\sigma^2$ as it would be for a real valued case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a legitimate concern. Why on earth would it still be $1$ if we have a complex mean? To address this concern, we need to use a little bit of measure theory to differentiate under the integral sign.

Let $\sigma, \mu_1\in \mathbb{R}$ and let us also define the following function function $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$:
$$F(\mu_2)=\int \frac {1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-(\mu_1+i\mu_2))^2}{2\sigma^2}} \, dx$$

Clearly, $F(0)=1$ and also because we have a function in the [Schwartz space](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1136255/1015934) we may use Lebesgue's Dominated Converence Theorem to differentiate under the integral sign to obtain:

$$F'(\mu_2)=\int \frac{\partial}{\partial \mu_2}\frac {1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-(\mu_1+i\mu_2))^2}{2\sigma^2}} \, dx=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-(\mu_1+i\mu_2))^2}{2\sigma^2}}\frac{-(x-(\mu_1+i\mu_2))(-i)}{\sigma^2}dx=\left.-i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-(\mu_1+i\mu_2))^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right|_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty}=0-0=0$$

Because $F'(\mu_2)=0$, both real and imaginary components must be constant! But $F(0)=1$. This means:

$$F(\mu_2)= 1 \quad \quad \forall \:\mu_2\in\mathbb{R} $$